# What is this javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain in detail what is going on here? Specifically the double dot notation.

```
(3.14).toFixed(); // "3"
3.14.toFixed(); // "3"

(3).toFixed(); // "3"
3.toFixed(); // SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
3..toFixed(); // "3"
```

[source](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-top-ten-things-a-beginner-must-know-about-JavaScript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [ECMA Script 5.1 Specifications](http://es5.github.io/#x7.8.3), grammar for decimal literals are defined like this

> ```
> DecimalLiteral ::
>
>    DecimalIntegerLiteral . [DecimalDigits] [ExponentPart]
>
>    . DecimalDigits [ExponentPart]
>
>    DecimalIntegerLiteral [ExponentPart]
> ```

<sub>**Note:** The square brackets are just to indicate that the parts are optional.</sub>

So, when you say

```
3.toFixed()
```

After consuming `3.`, the parser thinks that the current token is a part of a Decimal Literal, but it can only be followed by `DecimalDigits` or `ExponentPart`. But it finds `t`, which is not valid, that is why it fails with *SyntaxError*.

when you do

```
3..toFixed()
```

After consuming `3.`, it sees `.` which is called property accessor operator. So, it omits the optional `DecimalDigits` and `ExponentPart` and constructs a Floating point object and proceeds to invoke `toFixed()` method.

One way to overcome this is to leave a space after the number, like this

```
3 .toFixed()
```

Answer (score 8):

`3.` is a number, so the `.` is the decimal point and doesn't start a property.

`3..something` is a number followed by a property.